# Signing a Text in Java Using a (.PFX) Certificate Generated Under Windows

Tags: java, cryptography, digital-signature, pfx

We are having problems signing a string of text in Java using the .pfx certificate generated under windows. First, we executed the following steps in the order shown below on a Ubuntu Linux 12.0.4 LTS:

1. Converted the .pfx certificate to java keystore (jks) using the following commands:

   `openssl pkcs12 -in SupportTest-.pfx -out tempcertfile.crt -nodes`
2. Splited the certificate into two separate files:

   - A file containing the private key (key.pem)
   - Another file containing the rest (cert.pm)
3. Exported the key certificates in point 2) to a keystore of type PKCS12

   `openssl pkcs12 -export -in cert.pm -inkey key.pem -out aKeystore.p12 -name akeystore`
4. Convert pkcs12 keystore to a java keystore jks

   `keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore aKeystore.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -deskeystore akeystore.jks -destoretype jks`
5. Signing text messages with the private key retrieved from the jks ketstore

We used Java 7 to sign the text. We did not encounter any coding issue, and the `initVerify()` method in `java.security.Signature` returned `true`. The problem is that when the code is signed on Windows using the .Net platform, the signature is different than the one produced by Java. Both applications use the SHA256 with RSA.

Find below a code sample we used to sign the text:

```
Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256WithRSA");
signature.initSign(privateKey);
signature.update(dataToSign); 
return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(signature.sign()));
```

Comment: Please add sample of java code, where you signing text.

Answer (score 0):

Your java code and keystore looks good.

Maybe text encoding is different in C# and java and you getting different byte arrays to sign. In that case you will getting different result. Try to compare raw bytes before signing.

Maybe you are use different keys - double check path to private keys on both platform.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because the .NET code defaults to PSS and that you've specified a PKCS#1 v1.5 compatible padding in Java (`"SHA256WithRSA"`).

Comment: Without the .NET code it's hard to be sure of course, please add. I presume you've checked the input (dataToSign) to be fully identical on both platforms - as bytes.

Comment: Any progress on this, Vincent?